# How we can explain this by drawing a suitable diagram?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

When I go through the proof of [Riesz-Markov Representation Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Markov%E2%80%93Kakutani_representation_theorem)

I could encounter a step of defining

$A_k=K\cap f^{-1}((y_k,y_{k+1}))$

$U_k=V\cap f^{-1}((y_k,y_{k+1}))$

And the $A_k\in \mathcal B$ which is Borel sigma algebra, how it is??
And How we can explain this by drawing a suitable diagram? Give me a suitable function to explain geometrically.

Comment: I'm still not clear on what you're trying to do. Is your main goal to prove that $A_k$ is a Borel set, or something else? Can you tell us where you found this proof, or elaborate on the context yourself (i.e. explain the symbols such as $y_k$ and $A_k$, and whether you want to prove the $C_c$ version or the $C_0$ version)?

Comment: I will give the link to this article where i found this proof...@epimorphic

Comment: 35 th article in this page http://www.mtts.org.in/expository-articles